# What parts of a CRM solution are cumulative, and what parts are not?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Most solution changes are cumulative in CRM (adding an entity, adding a field to an entity, adding a form, etc) but some are not (site map is currently the only one that I know).  Does anyone have a list of the solution changes that are cumulative (safe to allow an auto-merge) and which changes are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK includes following two articles regarding your question:

- [Understand How Managed Solutions Are Merged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309329.aspx)
- [Introduction to Solutions - Conflict Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx#BKMK_ConflictResolution)

I'm currently not aware of a better description.